# Mysql INSERT INTO error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm getting this erro : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Especimes (nome_individual, data_de_nascimento) VALUES ('Amalia', '1' at line 7

while trying to run this:

```
INSERT INTO Especimes (nome_individual, data_de_nascimento) VALUES ('Amalia', '15/05/1998');
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Especimes (
nome_individual VARCHAR(64),
data_de_nascimento VARCHAR(64),
PRIMARY KEY(nome_individual)
)
```

Comment: That error is right before your query,I`m guessing you are running more than 1 query and you dont separate them

Comment: That is a big mistake **Never** store your `date` as `Varchar`

Comment: But how does it know the difference since it's just a string?

Comment: You can't do date arithmetic or sort by date if you store your date as a string.

Comment: I agree with @Mihai. There's something you're not telling us about how you run this query. I would guess you're trying to execute multiple SQL statements in one call. Even if you separate them by `;` the API doesn't support this.

Comment: `varchar` for the date... what in the f.. why?

Comment: I wanted the date to be in another format, since I didn't knew how I just though that if I insert as a string it would work.

Comment: ..the query you provided  is right .... have you a sequence of sql command? .. check if before of this query you have missed  the ;  for the previous command

Comment: You can use MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT()` function to format the date how you want it when you query it. But you should store it as a `date` data type. Anyway, **this has nothing to do with your error** so it's not pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query you provided is right .... have you a sequence of sql command? .. 
check if before of this query you have missed the ; for the previous command eg:

```
  CREATE TABLE Especimes (
  nome_individual VARCHAR(64),
  data_de_nascimento VARCHAR(64),
  PRIMARY KEY(nome_individual)
  )
  ;   /* add this */



INSERT INTO Especimes (nome_individual, data_de_nascimento) VALUES ('Amalia', '15/05/1998');
```

NB the use of proper data is better . (date ) instead of varchar  .. but is not the origin of your error

Comment: Thank you for your help but that isn't the problem since I'm using VARCHAR Data type for the date

Comment: Then if you use varchar  you should convert proeprly  .. i have update the answer ..

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: I was missing the ';'. This solved my problem! Thanks